# How to intercept SOAPMessage in WebSphere

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Can you help me out on this one?

I have a problem to struggle with. Before end user receives a response from web-service, I should sign the message, that is I extract the current SOAP message and invoke signing web-service. After I'm done, I just send it up the JAX-WS handlers chain. We have used JAX-WS handlers so far. The problem is that WebSphere sometimes refuses to pick up and invoke the handler. I mean, really. I've worked every angle and this just does not work. I've come up with an idea to do the signing in the module. I know it is not a good idea but I will think of something better after the signing procedure works once and for all. The major problem is that I do not know how to inject SOAPMessageContext in the module since WebSphere do it for JAX-WS handler automatically. I have neither not found the api reference to retrieve current SOAPMessageContext with ibm api, nor am I able to set the message in any other way. Is there a light at the end of the tonnel for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JAX-WS service it is possible to get the message context for the request, but it is not possible to manipulate the SOAP response inside the service itself. That is only possible in a handler.

I remember that in some of the recent WAS versions there was an issue where modifications to the SOAP message done by a JAX-WS handler are lost. Are you sure that WebSphere really doesn't invoke your handler, or could it be that the handler is invoked but that the modifications to the SOAP message are lost?

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for the reply. There is logging in a handler so - no, I do not think the handler is invoked.

Comment: In that case I would open a PMR with IBM support.